# How to emotionally cut free from an individual?

Tags: meditation-practicalities, daily-life

My friend meditates daily (non-Buddhist). He finds that from time to time a very annoying person tries to seemingly drag power and energy from him like a magnet.

Can any one explain how he can escape from this seemingly difficult situation? How can I advise him to emotionally cut free from this individual in his life?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem described here is all within the mind of your friend. The [Sigalovada Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.31.0.nara.html) explains, in our lives, we will encounter 'true friends' & 'false friends'. The [Sigalovada Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.31.0.nara.html) describes in detail the characteristics of 'true friends' & 'false friends'.

The method of escape is two-fold:

1. Discern clearly with wisdom the other person is a 'false-friend'.
2. Ensure this clear discernment is free from hatred & established in equanimity & concern (compassion).

Answer (score 1):

I had a situation like that. I tried to turn it into a practice to strengthen my patience and compassion(for both of us).